# Breadcrumb NavXT creating wrong href link

Tags: wordpress

I have used Breadcrumb NavXT plugin to create breadcrumbs for my site. I get the perfect breadcrumb trail as required but it creates a wrong href link for category page. How do I stop/solve that?

My required link :

```
http://www.example.com/category/xyz/
```

Plugin creates:

```
http://www.example.com/category/xyz/?post_type=netz_features
```

FYI: I have already asked for help from the plugin community but didn't get any response.

I would appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per my point, it is working proper. Please check again from your side.

Comment: @PriyankaModi Thanks for your reply.. I got the solution from my end. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got the answer to my own question. But anyone searching for the same issue, please follow these steps to save your day :)

To Remove post_type from Breadcrumb NavXT URLs, just copy & paste the below code into a [**site specific plugin**](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/).

```
add_filter('bcn_add_post_type_arg', 'my_add_post_type_arg_filt', 10, 3);
function my_add_post_type_arg_filt($add_query_arg, $type, $taxonomy)
{
    return false;
}
```

The above code is the most basic code that disables adding the post_type query argument for all resources.